# "Nothing remains to be done" meaning

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

I sent an email to my professor, requesting him to work on an action item pending his reply. The response I got is

> Nothing remains to be done.
>
> Professor X

I found this a little confusing. Does he mean

1. He has completed the action item, or
2. There are no action items pending his reply at the first place?

Answer (score 2):

"Nothing remains to be done" simply means that the process is complete.

Answer (score 0):

'Nothing remains to be done' means that there is nothing left to do.

The key to understanding what he means is the word 'remains'. 'To remain' means to stay in place.  When he says, 'Nothing remains', he means there was something there before but it is not there any more. I'm other words, there was something for him to do,  but it has been done. So it is the first of your options.